# How to get non-playstore Android app detected as a "Game" in game launcher apps of Samsung, OnePlus etc

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I have a Samsung S21 (OS 12) device having Samsung's "Game Launcher" app.
Non-playstore apps like Winzo, Zupee etc which are downloaded from their respective websites show automatically in the Game Launcher app as soon as they are installed.
However, my app does not show automatically. Also when I try adding my app to Game Launcher, it says "**<app_name> isn't a game. Some services won't be available for it**". So the game mode settings are not showing when my app is running.

I have tried the following:

- Adding **android:isGame="true"** in application tag of androidmanifest
- Adding **android:appCategory="game"** in application tag of androidmanifest
- Adding **android:hardwareAccelerated="true"** in application tag of androidmanifest
- Adding **OpenGL** to the app `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />`
- Playing around with application id names such as keeping it com.example.myapplication

None of the above worked. Same is the case with "Games" app in OnePlus.
I have already checked all the existing sources on StackO.

How can I get my app detected as a Game by these apps?